# Operator overloading outside a template class with implicit conversions

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have a template class defined like this

```
template<class T> class Wrap
{
    /* ... */
public:
    Wrap(const T&);
    /* other implicit conversions */

    /* ... */
};
```

I want to define all the comparison operators for this class outside the class like this

```
template<typename T> bool operator == (const Wrap<T>&, const Wrap<T>&)
{
    // Do comparison here
}
```

This declaration however doesn't support implicit conversions of `const T&`, or any other type, to `const Wrap<T>&`.

So my question is how do I make it support implicit conversions when either one of the operands is of type `Wrap<T>` and the other is not. I don't want to write multiple declarations of each operator for every possible permutation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
template<class T> struct is_wrap : std::false_type {};
template<class T> struct is_wrap<Wrap<T>> : std::true_type {};

template<class T1, class T2> typename std::enable_if<is_wrap<typename std::common_type<T1, T2>::type>::value, bool>::type operator == (const T1& t1, const T2& t2)
{
    const typename std::common_type<T1, T2>::type& tc1 = t1, tc2 = t2;
    // compare with tc1 and tc2
}
```

Comment: Great answer. I'm guessing u missed the reference for 'tc2' though.

Answer (score 1):

Someone else will articulate this better, but I think the problem is that the compiler can't deduce `T` in `Wrap<T>` without you passing it a `Wrap` object. I think your situation should be resolved if you explicitly give the `operator==` a template argument: `operator==<int>(7, 4)`, for example should work.

I don't have a compiler in front of me, but here's my try:

```
template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_convertible<Wrap<T>, T>::value, bool>::type operator==(const Wrap<T>& l, const T& r)
{
    return l.stuff == Wrap<T>(r).stuff;
}

template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_convertible<Wrap<T>, T>::value, bool>::type operator==(const T& l, const Wrap<T>& r)
{
    return r == l; // call above operator
}
```

This should work if either side is a `Wrap` and the other side isn't. You could also do both sides as `const T&`, however if `Wrap` is really implicitly constructible from any `T` you will wind up using your `operator==` for many unintended comparisons, even of `int`s, `string`s, etc.

Comment: This still requires me to add 2 other declarations for each operator which I wanted to avoid.